# ChartJS x-axis show only months of year

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, chart.js

So I'm making this mobile app using Cordova, which allows me to use HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I'm currently using SQLite as a database (works almost same as mySQL) but that isn't that important. All I do is get my data from that database. I get both the date (of when the data was added to the Database) and the weight of a person.

I'm using a linegraph which show the weight on the Y-axis and the data on the X-axis.

What I want to do is only show the months as labels on the x-axis but still make it so that it show data for each day seperate. So for example if I add data on the 1st of January, the 2nd of January and the 3rd of January. I want to be able to see all 3 days as dots on my graph but on the X-axis it should only say 'January'.

I've been looking into the 'time' option of Chart.JS but can't really make any sense of how I'm supposed to do it.

HTML:

```
<canvas id="myChart" style="margin-top: 20px;"></canvas>
```

JavaScript:

```
//these are the arrays that I will fill dynamically. Labels will be my months and data will be the weight

var labels = []; 
var data = [];

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'line',

    // The data for our dataset
    data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 119, 0, 0.5)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 119, 0, 1)',
            data: data
        }]
    },

    // Configuration options go here
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the time-type in your x-axis. With `time: { unit: 'month' }` (always months) or `minUnit` (months and years if necessary) you can get the month labels.

As label for your data you need to pass a `Date` or `moment`

```
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    type: 'time',
    time: {
      unit: 'month'
    }
  }],
}
```

[Here](https://jsbin.com/welikobola/edit?html,js,output) is a complete example.
Check the [moment docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/) for dates, especially the creation and parsing of dates. Chart.js works with moment dates so it's quite important (and quite easy btw).